# Two different samples with the same result in the Shapiro Wilk test

Tags: r, random

Two different samples generated with the `rnorm` function produce the same result in the Shapiro-Wilk test. I would greatly appreciate an explanation of my error.

```
> set.seed(18102003)
> x=rnorm(n=6,mean=1.29,sd=1.29*0.33)
> x
[1] 2.0989973 1.5440310 0.8401053 1.3630999 1.3274229 1.9812853
> shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.94929, p-value = 0.7345

> set.seed(18102003)
> x=rnorm(6,2.97,2.97*0.49)
> x
[1] 5.735642 3.838432 1.431988 3.219900 3.097934 5.333231
> shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.94929, p-value = 0.7345
```

Comment: If you do `z <- rnorm(n = 6); shapiro.test(z)` you will see the same values, the vectors `x` and `z` are just scaled versions of the same `z`. Compute `scale(x) - scale(z)` and see that the differences are not distinguishable from zero.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, please post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Done, a bit more verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tests' results are exactly the same because the vectors are copies of one another scaled and the Shapiro-Wilks test is invariant to changes in location and scale. This can be seen if we compute the differences between the scaled vectors.

First, generate the vectors again, but assigning them different names, and a new vector `z`.

```
set.seed(18102003)
x <- rnorm(n = 6, mean = 1.29, sd = 1.29*0.33)
set.seed(18102003)
y <- rnorm(6, 2.97, 2.97*0.49)
set.seed(18102003)
z <- rnorm(n = 6)
```

Now see that `x` and `y` are copies of `z`

```
all.equal(x, 1.29*0.33*z + 1.29)
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(y, 2.97*0.49*z + 2.97)
#[1] TRUE

scale(x) - scale(y)  # equal up to floating-point precision
scale(x) - scale(z)  # the same
```

Now run the tests, and compare the tests statistics with `identical`.

```
identical(shapiro.test(z)$statistic, shapiro.test(x)$statistic)
#[1] TRUE
identical(shapiro.test(z)$statistic, shapiro.test(y)$statistic)
#[1] TRUE
```